# Hide div element if it is empty (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have ajax call like this

```
  $('#display').click(function () {
        var vacancyId = $("#vacancy").val();
        var model = {
            vacancyId: vacancyId
    };

        $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("QuestionBlocks", "Questions")',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var question1 = data[0]

        $(".list").append('<div style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;;">' + question1.Question1 + '</div>' + '<div style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question2 + '</div>' + '<div style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question3 + '</div>' + '<div style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question4 + '</div>' + '<div style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question5 + '</div>' + '<div style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question6 + '</div>' + '<div style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question7 + '</div>' + '<div style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question8 + '</div>' + '<div style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question9 + '</div>' + '<div style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color: #ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question10 + '</div>');
        $(".list").find('div.section:empty').hide();
         }
    });
});
```

But some divs are empty because values from back-end are null.

I need to hide empty divs

I try this `$(".list").find('div.section:empty').hide();` but it seems not works.

What I wrote wrong in code?

Comment: Where do you add the class `section` to your `div`s

Comment: as carsten says, there are no section divs being appended, try `$(".list").children('div:empty').hide();`

Comment: Sorry, seems I understood my mistake. Will try one solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily using javascript Only. In this approach, you will get all the div's, check if they are empty and hide them accordingly.

```
var req = document.getElementsByClassName('list');
for(j=0; j<req.length; j++)
{
    var divs = req[j].innerHTML.getElementsByTagName('div');// got all the divs in the current element

    for(i=0; i<divs.length; i++)
    {
        if(divs[i].innerHTML == "")
        {
        divs[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all the div from the page

Comment: he only wants div inside ".list" class. Why all divs?

Comment: @madalinivascu fixed it

Comment: It hides all my div in list

Comment: @Eugene Really?? it should not. we have checked for empty before hiding. This suggests that all your div's are empty when you run this function. Make sure to run it after the ajax call returns. Most probably it is getting executed before that. You can try moving it to a callback function

Comment: It's great to know that